# Perl: use Module @list

Tags: perl, perl-module

Someone has an idea to use array variable in place of array (list) literal, in the `use` function statement, like:

```
my @list = qw(foo zoo);
use Module @list;
```

instead of

```
use Module qw(foo zoo);
```

So she writes e.g.:

```
my @consts = qw(PF_INET PF_INET6);
use Socket @consts;
printf "%d, %d\n", PF_INET, PF_INET6;
```

which seemingly works as expected:

> 2, 10

Then she is doing it with some other module, e.g. `Time::HiRes`. Instead of

```
use Time::HiRes qw(CLOCK_REALTIME CLOCK_MONOTONIC);
printf "%d, %d\n", CLOCK_REALTIME, CLOCK_MONOTONIC;
```

> 0, 1

she does:

```
my @consts = qw(CLOCK_REALTIME CLOCK_MONOTONIC);
use Time::HiRes @consts;
printf "%d, %d\n", CLOCK_REALTIME, CLOCK_MONOTONIC;
```

> 0, 0

It suddenly does not work, like it worked with `Socket` module!
Something bad is happening here.

(.. it's in non-strict environment. If she used `use strict`, she would even have gotten an error. On the other hand, she gets no hint at all in her first seemingly working example - even when she has `use strict; use warnings; use diagnostics` there.)

Now she wants to explore this weird behavior. Tries importing an empty list:

```
my @consts = ();
use Socket @consts;
printf "%d, %d\n", PF_INET, PF_INET6;
```

> 2, 10

surprisingly works as well, while it probably should not, like:

```
use Socket ();
printf "%d, %d\n", PF_INET, PF_INET6;
```

> 0, 0

Then she digs a little into those modules a little and realizes, that that the difference between the two modules is that these constants are / are not `@EXPORT`ed, respectively.

Her conclusion is that the `use Module @list` does not work as she is expecting.

What would be the best explanation for that? What is she doing wrong - What is the correct way of using pre-defined array in the `use` statement?

Comment: Re "Tries importing an empty list ... surprisingly works as well", Why? `use foo @foo;` is no different than `use foo;`. Both provide an empty list. `use foo ();` would also pass an empty list, but it's a special *syntax*.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This has to do with when the code is executed. `use` is executed at compile time, while the `my @list` is only executed at runtime. So the array does not exist a the point the module is loaded.

The module [Socket exports](https://metacpan.org/source/PEVANS/Socket-2.013/Socket.pm#L701) `PF_INET` and `PF_INET6` by default, so it doesn't matter if you put it in the `use` line. But Time::HiRes [does not export stuff](https://metacpan.org/source/ZEFRAM/Time-HiRes-1.9726/HiRes.pm#L11) by default.

The error you get with `strict` is:

> Bareword "CLOCK_REALTIME" not allowed while "strict subs" in use ...

That tells us that Perl does not know that `CLOCK_REALTIME` is a sub, which is true, because it was not loaded when we do this:

```
my @consts = qw(CLOCK_REALTIME CLOCK_MONOTONIC);
use Time::HiRes @consts;
printf "%d, %d\n", CLOCK_REALTIME, CLOCK_MONOTONIC;
```

[What `use` does](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) is `require` the module and `import` the LIST of arguments at compile time. So it's the same as:

```
BEGIN {
  require foo;
  foo->import();
}
```

Knowing that, we can do it ourselves:

```
use strict; use warnings;
BEGIN { 
  my @consts = qw(CLOCK_REALTIME CLOCK_MONOTONIC);
  require Time::HiRes;
  Time::HiRes->import(@consts);
}

printf "%d, %d\n", CLOCK_REALTIME, CLOCK_MONOTONIC;

__END__
0, 1
```

Like this it will work, because the array `@const` is defined in the same scope and is already available when the Perl interpreter executes it.

Because of scoping, just adding a `BEGIN` block in front of the use will **not** work.

```
BEGIN {
  my @consts = qw(CLOCK_REALTIME CLOCK_MONOTONIC);
}

use Time::HiRes (@consts);
```

You can get around the problem by declaring the variable outside the `BEGIN` block. That way it will be available in the next `BEGIN` block's scope, and the value will already be set because the [`BEGIN` blocks are executed at compile time in FIFO order](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN,-UNITCHECK,-CHECK,-INIT-and-END).

```
my @consts;
BEGIN {
  @consts = qw(CLOCK_REALTIME CLOCK_MONOTONIC);
}

use Time::HiRes (@consts);
printf "%d, %d\n", CLOCK_REALTIME, CLOCK_MONOTONIC;

__END__
0, 1
```

---

So to recap:

- it's because of two things: **scope** and **order of execution**
- the fact that you pass an array is not the issue here - the array will be [part of the LIST](http://friedo.com/blog/2013/07/arrays-vs-lists-in-perl) that is passed
- if you do not `use strict`, you cannot easily find the problem
- if you add a `BEGIN` block in front of the `use` and place the `my` declaration outside the `BEGIN`, it works
- if you take `require` instead of `use` and `import` yourself, you can also pass an array

Comment: Needlessly advocated `no strict;`. Fixed.

Comment: You can also do `use foo do { my @syms = ...; ...; @syms; };`

Comment: Very nice. Funny is, that she's stil unhappy, because she finnaly wanted to do: `printf "%d, %d\n", @consts`, which is obviously wrong. Or, without importing, this also also doesn't work by her means: `print Time::HiRes::$consts[0]`. How can she use a string as a "symbol"?

Comment: @mykhal: `no strict 'refs'; printf "%d, %d\n", map &{$_}(), @consts`. This takes the strings inside `@consts` as the name of a sub and executes it. Only works if `strict refs` are turned off. Makes sense to wrap that part in a very short block so it doesn't affect the rest of the code.

Comment: @ikegami: thank you for pointing that out and fixing the answer. On the other hand, the OP said *it's in non-strict environment*, so I did not think it would matter that much. ;)

Comment: @mykhal: technically this should be a new question.

Comment: @simbabque, We don't write strict-safe code because we use `use strict;`. We write strict-safe code because it's the right thing to do. `use strict;` is a check to make sure we're doing the right thing.

Comment: This is a very well written answer. Every time I thought "*this should mention ...*" it was the very next thing that was mentioned.